# Как при переводе из строки в число проконтролировать наличие символов в строке?

Tags: строки, c++

Например
string s = "1a";
int value = atoi(s[i].c_str());
На выходе имею 1, а нужно, чтобы строка как-то забраковывалась, например чтобы ее можно было отловить через try-catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте [Boost.Lexical_Cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

При попытке конвертировать в число строку, содержащую символы, отличные от цифр, выбрасывается исключение `bad_lexical_cast`:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using boost::lexical_cast;
using boost::bad_lexical_cast;

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string numstr ("2777dd");
    try {
        int ii = lexical_cast<int> (numstr);
        cout << ii << endl;
    }
    catch (bad_lexical_cast&) {
        cerr << "Not a number\n";   
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Boost это "тяжелая артиллерия".

Если хочется попроще, без ловли исключений или на чистом Си, то используйте `strtol()` из `libc`

Например, такая программка читает массив целых, разделяемых пробелами, запятыми и табуляциями.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DELIM " ,\t\n\r"

// сделаем массив целых из строки и вернем его адрес
// по адресу *pn положим количество чисел в нем
int *
iarr (char *s, int *pn)
{
  int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(*arr) * strlen(s)), n = 0;
  char *p, *str = s;

  while (s += strspn(s,DELIM), *s) {
    arr[n++] = strtol(s,&p,10); // читаем десятичное целое
    if (*p && !strchr(DELIM,*p)) {  // анализируем правильность
      printf ("invalid char '%c' (%02x) in pos %d\n",
          *p,(u_char)*p,p-str);
      free(arr);
      return NULL;
    }
    s = *p? p+1: p;
  }

  *pn = n;
  return arr;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char buf[1000];
  int  *arr, n, i;

  while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin)) {
    if (arr = iarr(buf,&n)) {
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf ("arr[%d] = %d\n",i,arr[i]);
      free(arr);
    }
  }

  exit (0);
}
```

Конечно, если несколько запятых подряд это ошибка, то нужен более изощренный разбор строки, а тогда уж проще самому преобразовать цепочку цифр в число.

Comment: Судя по объему кода, еще вопрос - что на самом деле "тяжелая артиллерия" )))

Comment: Да, ну?

    const char *ns = "123dd";
    char *p;
    int nn = strtol(ns,&p,10);
    if (*p && !isspace(*p))
       printf ("error in %d\n",p-ns);
    else
       printf ("number is %d\n",nn);


IMHO то же самое, только никаких дополнительных библиотек, инклюдников, наверняка кучи соглашений, что и как надо делать, чтобы вся система не завалилоась и т.п.

Comment: Да вообще-то инклюдник только один включается. Дополнительных библиотек не нужно, т.к. все в инклюдниках. Спокойно работает как char, так и с wchar_t. В линуксах Boost устанавливается из репозиториев на раз-два.

Единственный минус - работает только с десятичной системой

Comment: Кстати, в C++11 появились еще аналогичные функции, типа stoi, только там второй параметр - size_t*, куда передается индекс.

Comment: @mikillskegg, а что Boost на самом деле прост и хорош (я просто совсем с ним не знаком) или требует глубокого понимания плюсов, а в противном случае все будет работать криво?

И еще, если это один набор инклюдников, то в чем проблема в установке на любую систему?

И, кстати, еще. Интересно было бы посмотреть на реализацию iarr() (или чего-то подобного) из моего примера с использованием Boost.

Comment: В Boost куча разных библиотек. Одни очень простые, другие очень сложные. Некоторые сложные вещи делают очень простыми (например, написание бинарных модулей для Питона). Некоторые библиотеки состоят только из инклюдников, другие требуют скомпилированных библиотек.

Comment: Да, я уже посмотрел www.boost.org/...

Много всего, это точно. При поверхностном обзоре создается впечатление, что изучать надо... (а часто кажется, что для конкретного случая проще самому написать, чем чужое освоить).